# AJAX recursive callback on completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have a database which needs to be deleted via batch process. As shown in the code below, there can be any number of `step` (current batch iteration) depending on the database size. I want to place the function `redirect_to_homepage()` somewhere in the below code so that after the last batch process, it redirects to a new page. Currently, it redirects as soon as the `response.success` is true, instead I want it to wait for all iterations of `delete_all_data()` to finish and then redirect. How can I achieve this?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'action': 'deactivation_form_submit',
        'form-data': form_data,
    }
}).done( function( response ) {

    if ( response.success ) {
        if ( response.data.delete_data ) {
            delete_all_data( 1, form_data );
        }

        redirect_to_homepage();
    }
});

// This is a recursive AJAX function.
function delete_all_data( step, form_data ) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'form': form_data,
            'action': 'give_do_ajax_export',
            'step': step,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done( function( response ) {
        if ( true !== response.success && ! response.error ) {
            delete_all_data( parseInt( response.step ), form_data );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Determine what means `all`, make `delete_all_data` return true or false whether or not it still has something to delete, and redirect only if there is nothing else to delete. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `redirect_to_homepage()` method as callback which will execute when a desired condition is achieved.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    .....
}).done( function( response ) {
    if ( response.success  response.data.delete_data ) {
         delete_all_data( 1, form_data, redirect_to_homepage ); //Pass function reference   
    }
});

// This is a recursive AJAX function.
function delete_all_data( step, form_data, cb ) {
    jQuery.ajax({
       .....
    }).done( function( response ) {
        if ( true !== response.success && ! response.error ) {
            delete_all_data( parseInt(response.step,10), form_data, cb);  //Pass function reference   
        }else{
            //At present assuming this 
            //Invoke the callback function 
            cb();  
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the synchronous ajax call for your `delete_all_data` ajax call something like this

```
function delete_all_data( step, form_data ) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        async:false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'form': form_data,
            'action': 'give_do_ajax_export',
            'step': step,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done( function( response ) {
        if ( true !== response.success && ! response.error ) {
            delete_all_data( parseInt( response.step ), form_data );
        }
    });
}
```

This will stop the execution of the redirect till the last call of `delete_all_data` has been executed.

Other option if you dont want to use synchronous call then us the function as function as follows

```
function delete_all_data( step, form_data ) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        async:false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'form': form_data,
            'action': 'give_do_ajax_export',
            'step': step,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done( function( response ) {
        if ( true !== response.success && ! response.error ) {

            if(response.step != last) {/// check if this is not the last step
            delete_all_data( parseInt( response.step ), form_data );
           }
           else{
                ////// Your redirection code goes here (function call or direct window.location.href)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Let us know if it helps

Comment: Don't use `async:false`.